# ¿Cómo comparar disponibilidad de horarios en una tabla de reservas con php?

Tags: php, laravel, blade

Lo que deseo hacer es validar es que al hacer una reserva me valide que ya esta ocupado, pero actualmente lo único que hago es que valide horarios entre. Ejemplo:
Ya existe una reserva de 8:00 a 20:horas, Ya logre que si alguien más reserva por ejemplo de 9:00 a 19:00 horas (entre el rango de horas), pero no logro hacer para cuando se reserva ejemplo: 06:00 a 13:00 únicamente 13 esta entre el rango de la reserva.

```
function esta_ocupado($dia, $horarioinicio, $horariofin, $id_amenidad){

$valores = [];
 $Reservas = Reservas::where("dia", date($dia))->where("amenidad_id", $id_amenidad)->get();


 foreach ($Reservas as $re) {
     if (($horarioinicio >=  $re->horario_inicio_id && $horarioinicio <= $re->horario_fin_id) || ($horariofin >=  $re->horario_inicio_id && $horariofin <= $re->horario_fin_id) ) {
       array_push($valores, true);

     }else{
         array_push($valores, false);
     }
 }

foreach ($valores as $val) {
    if ($val) {
      return true;
    }
}

return false;

}
```

Comment: puedes proporcionar los atributos de la tabla que usas?

Answer (score 1):

Para determinar si dos intervalos se interceptan prueba esta regla

```
start0 < end1 and end0 > start1
```

Donde los `[start0, end0]` puede ser la reserva hecha y `[start1, end1]` puede ser la reserva que se esta solicitando o al reves. Si la condición se cumple entonces los intervalos se interceptan

Usando tus datos de ejemplo:

```
08:00 < 13:00 and 20:00 > 06:00
```

La condicion evalua a true, es decir, ya existe una reserva en ese horario